# Appium Android Testing Using UIAutomator showing error while trying Image Upload Feature

Tags: testing, appium, appium-android, uiautomatorviewer

I am facing some Issue during Appium Testing Using UIAutomator

I need to Automate payment page but After try to take screenshot during testing it show me error .

[image]

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Using UI Automator file upload feature you can  upload screenshot manually .

1. Take screenshot of screen which you need to Automate.
2. Open command Prompt and Enter below Command :-

adb shell uiautomator dump && adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml && start window_dump.xml
UI hierchary dumped to: /sdcard/window_dump.xml

3.Its open xml in browser copy that path.

4.Open your UI Automator and click on file and upload  button and add screenshot and xml file.

5.You can see you screen and Element in UI Automator Viewer Now.

for More details check below link also:-

https://medium.com/@sagartripathi/appium-android-using-uiautomator-using-image-upload-ae5943f747c6